# count in excel how many days had negative temperature

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a table

```
Date        Time    Temp
1/08/2020   12 am   10.5
1/08/2020   1 am    10.25
1/08/2020   2 am    10
1/08/2020   3 am    10.25
1/08/2020   4 am    10.5
1/08/2020   5 am    10.5
```

so on for a whole month.
I'd like to know how many nights the temperature was below XX.

I used COUNTIF to count how many times the temperature was below XX, but can't figure out how to translate that into how many nights (or 24 hour periods).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your version of Excel, I would suggest a "Helper Column"

eg:  `D2: =IF(A2<>A1,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/($A$2:$A$18=A2)*$C$2:$C$18,1),"")`

and fill down.

Then, just do a simple `COUNTIF` on the helper column for your threshold:

eg:  `G2: =COUNTIF($D$1:$D$18,"<="&F2)`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*I would like to suggest two possible methods to determine Days & Nights, can be used further to count Nights, has negative temperature.:*

[image]

**Method 1:**

For AM:

```
 J32   =SUMPRODUCT(--(HOUR($F$32:$F$39)<12))
```

For PM:

```
 J33   =SUMPRODUCT(--(HOUR($F$32:$F$39)>12))
```

**Method 2:**

- Formula in cell H32:

  ```
  =IF(MOD(F32,1)>=0.5,"PM","AM")
  ```

*In this formula >0.5 find the half-day mark, and separates AM and PM.*

- Then use COUNIF in cell J35 & J36:

For AM:

```
 J35   =COUNTIF($H$32:$H$39,I35)
```

For PM:

```
  J36  =COUNTIF($H$32:$H$39,I36)
```

**:Edited:**

*Purpose behind edited part is to suggest OP that how to count Days/Nights has Negative temperature.*

- Formula in K35 (fill it down ):

  ```
    =COUNTIFS($H$32:$H$39,$I35,$G$32:$G$39,"<0")
  ```
- Or you can use this also to find Night has negative temperature.

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT((--(HOUR($F$32:$F$39)>12))*($G$32:$G$39<0))
  ```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

*You may replace AM/PM with Day/Night.*